# OpenCL data parallel kernel, not enough work items?

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, opencl

I've been working to implement a Particle Swarm Optimizer (PSO) with OpenCL after having done it on c++. However I'm currently stuck and don't know why the kernels don't compute as I want. Before i proceed I'll show you my specs that I got by running the first example from: https://github.com/HandsOnOpenCL/Exercises-Solutions

Number of OpenCL plaforms: 1

---

Platform: Apple
    Vendor:  Apple
    Version: OpenCL 1.2 (Sep 21 2015 19:24:11)

```
Number of devices: 2
-------------------------
    Name: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4278U CPU @ 2.60GHz
    Version: OpenCL C 1.2 
    Max. Compute Units: 4
    Local Memory Size: 32 KB
    Global Memory Size: 8192 MB
    Max Alloc Size: 2048 MB
    Max Work-group Total Size: 1024
    Max Work-group Dims: (1024 1 1)
-------------------------
-------------------------
    Name: Iris
    Version: OpenCL C 1.2 
    Max. Compute Units: 40
    Local Memory Size: 64 KB
    Global Memory Size: 1536 MB
    Max Alloc Size: 384 MB
    Max Work-group Total Size: 512
    Max Work-group Dims: (512 512 512)
-------------------------
```

---

Now what I currently want to do with the PSO is to evaluate each particle and I want to do it with the following kernel:

```
__kernel void EvaluateParticles(__global float* particlePositions,__global int* numberOfVariables,__global int* numberOfParticles,__global float* fitness)
{

    int idx = get_global_id(0);
    int nVar = numberOfVariables;

    fitness[idx] = idx;//Optimized function goes here later

}
```

Now the kernel is working and compiling however, the issue is that I currently have 20 particles I want to evaluate. When I run the code the fitness array only gets initialized from element 0 to 15, meaning only 16 parallel threads are running in the kernel?

I enqueue the kernel from the host side with the following command:

```
size_t global_item_size = 20;
size_t local_item_size = 1;

ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL, 
                             &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, &event);
```

Question 1: How come only 16 threads run? Even if I change the global_item_size variable nothing changes. From the specs in the beginning of the post it says I should have 40 parallel compute units? I'm clearly not grasping something.

Question 2: If you only have N possible work-items / compute units to utilize, but got M (Assume M>N and evenly dividable by N: M/N = integer) threads u want to run, or in this instance, M particles to evaluate. Is there any simple way to make the threads work twice? With an updated index?

Thank you for your time and I hope that my questions have been clearly formulated!

Comment: Have you tried running some of the samples to check if they make use of more than 16 threads? What exactly do you mean by work twice?

Comment: @nabla Say that you have 16 work items, but each element of your array with size 32 has to be processed. Is it possible to use some kind of loop for the work items so after they finished the first "run" that it goes back and gets an increase of the index? E.g, a work item gets the global-id of 0. It processes the things it has to do and stores the results in fitness[0]. When this is done it gets re-used again and does the same thing but now grabs global-id 16. This way you can have 16 work items, filling out or processing an array that is of size 32.
The samples from the git repo?

Comment: Excercise02 from the repo adds two 1024 long vectors with eachother.. And it works when I run it. The kernel isn't much different from the one I've written. So I'll have to check it out. It's written in C but it shouldn't matter porting it to C++?

Comment: Why do you think it is only working for 16 threads? The kernel looks fine; it must be your host code.

Comment: The number of CUs does not matter. Just launch as many threads as you need. Preferably with number of threads per block more than one, e.g. 64.

Comment: @Dithermaster When i print the 20 element fitness array only the first 16 elements are initialized. E,g fitness = [0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 (random small uninitialized number) (random small uninitialized number) (random small uninitialized number) (random small uninitialized number)]

Comment: Typical problems are to forget that when reading data from CL, you need to specify the amount in bytes, not in number of elements. Therefore you are only reading a portion of it. We can't check that without the host code.

Comment: @DarkZeros Yea. I changed the code a bit, and used the examples from the github repo. I've managed to get it to work now